# Understanding on Mutual TLS , client config with servername

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2

I am trying to understand the mutual TLS working, I have the following example:

> I have a client who wants to connect to server  "svc1.example.com"

but the server has a

> server certificate with a commonName as "svc1.example.cloud" and a SAN
>   as "svc.example.test.cloud".

Now when I make a GET request, I get the following:

***x509: certificate is valid for svc.example.test.cloud, not svc1.example.com.***

So, my question is should I make a the TLS clientConfig changes to include the servername? or should I add a custom verifyPeerCertificate function in the TLS client config, something like below?

**Please, let me know, what should be the Servername and what should I check for in the verifyPeerCertificate function.**

```
func customverify(customCName func(*x509.Certificate) bool) func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
    if customCName == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return func(_ [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
        for _, certs := range verifiedChains {
            leaf := certs[0]
            if customCName(leaf) {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("client identity verification failed")
    }
}




func configureClient(certFile, keyFile string) (*http.Client, error) {
    certpool, err := addRootCA()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
transport := ytls.NewClientTransport()
transport.TLSClientConfig.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{cert}
transport.TLSClientConfig.RootCAs = certpool
//transport.TLSClientConfig.ServerName = expectedCName
transport.TLSClientConfig.VerifyPeerCertificate = customverify(func(cert *x509.Certificate) bool {
    return cert.Subject.CommonName == "svc1.example.cloud"
})

httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
return httpClient, nil
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **x509: certificate is valid for svc.example.test.cloud**, so `transport.TLSClientConfig.ServerName = "svc.example.test.cloud"`

From https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config

> VerifyPeerCertificate, if not nil, is called after normal
>    certificate verification by either a TLS client or server. It
>    receives the raw ASN.1 certificates provided by the peer and also
>    any verified chains that normal processing found. If it returns a
>    non-nil error, the handshake is aborted and that error results.
>
> If normal verification fails then the handshake will abort before
>    considering this callback. If normal verification is disabled by
>    setting InsecureSkipVerify, or (for a server) when ClientAuth is
>    RequestClientCert or RequireAnyClientCert, then this callback will
>    be considered but the verifiedChains argument will always be nil.

**VerifyPeerCertificate func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error**

So if normal verification fails, then `VerifyPeerCertificate` won't get called. Also if normal verification is passed, i don't think you need this extra check `VerifyPeerCertificate`.